# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'omp.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-c++, openmp

I am running a .cpp code on MS Visual Express C++ 2010.

It runs fine. After that I added OpenMP statements and included the omp.h header file.
When I run it, I get the following error:

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'omp.h': No such file or directory`

Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the path to the OpenMP headers in your project settings?

Comment: Are you compiling with /openmp?

Comment: @dirkgently - I wrote `#include <omp.h> ' in the beginning of the code. I don't know how to add the path to the OpenMP header in the Properties section.

@Tudor - Since I am using MS Visual C++ Express, I do not need to compile as compared to command line. I click the 'Compile' on the page.

Comment: I went to the _Properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> OpenMP Support_ . I set that to 'Yes'.

Comment: And it still didnt work!

Comment: Are you including any other header files? Have you checked if you have the file `omp.h` in your visual studio include folder?

Comment: @Tudor - I checked. Its not there. Also I found out that MS Visual C++ Express edition does not support OpenMP. Moreover, I tried to find opm.h header file, so that I can include it in the Visual C++ Express include folder. But I could not find such omp.h header file to download. Yes, I am including the usual header files like iostream, time.

[link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs24szh9(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP is not available in Visual C++ 2010 Express edition.
[msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you are stil using VS express and OpenMP, you can use use this: http://www.ssidelnikov.ru/en/2011/05/openmp-visual-studio-2010-express/